# Wordpress Loop does not work properly in category.php when using query_posts

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I am developing a wordpress theme. I am new in this field, and it's not very easy.

I wrote the code for the loop, and everything is working perfectly. I am working on category.php page. Without the query posts, the category is correctly showing the posts from that specific category.

But, I want to add pagination, and limit the posts per page to maybe 10. But, when I add this code before the loop:

```
<?php query_posts( 'posts_per_page=10' ); ?>
```

It doesn't work. Now, it outputs all the posts, from every category in the website, not only from that category.

Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

`query_posts( 'cat=3&year=2004' );`

You need to add the category to the query_posts; otherwise wordpress won't know you need a category in your **custom** query.

Comment: Thanks, but I need a dynamic code, so I won't have to put the category id there, but it will find the current category id and show the posts for that category.

Comment: query_posts('cat='.$cat); Do you want to try something like this ?

Answer (score 0):

What you'll need to do is set how many posts you want to display on the page via **Settings -> Reading** and WP should take care of the pagination.

If you theme framework doesn't have a pagination function, I would recommend something like:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/
http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-visualpagination/

Those give you a simple PHP code to put into your theme wherever you want the pagination to show up. The code will have to be put between the **endwhile;** and **endif;** inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to dynamically pass the current category's ID into the query:

```
query_posts('posts_per_page=10&cat='.get_query_var('cat'));
```